# Send bulk email with MailKit in C#

Tags: c#, mailkit

We are using `MailKit` to successfully send emails by creating a client, making a connection and sending a mail. Very standard stuff which works great as we receive a message in our application, we do something and send on an email.
However we want to be able to **process 10's of thousands of emails** as quickly as possible.
Our destination email server may be unavailable and therefore we could quickly backup messages therefore producing a backlog.

With `MailKit`, what is the best and quickwest way to process the mails so that they get sent as quickly as possible. For example at the moment each mail may be processed one after the other and if they take a second each to process it could take a long time to send 40000 mails.

We have been using a `parallel foreach` to spin up a number of threads but this has limitations. Any suggestions or recommendations would be appreciated.

Code sample added: *CORRECTION, NEW CODE SAMPLE ADDED. This is much faster but I cannot get it to work creating a new connection each time. Exchange throws errors 'sender already specified'. This is currently sending around 6 mails per second on average.*

```
            var rangePartitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, inpList.Count, 15);

            var po = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 30 };


            Parallel.ForEach(rangePartitioner, (range, loopState) =>
            {
                using (var client = new SmtpClient(new SlabProtocolLogger()))
                {

                    client.Connect(_appSettings.RelayAddress, _appSettings.RelayPort);
                    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

                    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
                    {

                        var message = _outboundQueueRepository.Read(inpList[i]).Load();
                        client.Send(message.Body, message.Metadata.Sender, message.Metadata.Recipients.Select(r => (MailboxAddress)r));

                        _outboundQueueRepository.Remove(inpList[i]);
                    };
                }

            });
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a code sample : the `parallel foreach`

Comment: Always edit code into the question, not into comments. Then you don't have to apologize for formatting

Comment: Yes, thanks. Hopefully this is better.

Comment: firstly i would assume that your task is mostly waiting for io - completion, so you could increase the parallelism. Secondly, wouldn't you need a client for each task? can you really use the same client to send multiple messages at the same time? I would assume that client.send locks the socket, so despie for || foreach you are only sending one message at a time...

Comment: Hi, as mentioned in the comments we have tried increasing the parallelism but it doesn't make much difference. Tried it at 10, 50 and -1 (unlimited I believe). I don't know how I would work around this without writing more code. Yes, using the same client works but we have also tried the creation of the client for each message by placing this inside the loop. Still works but makes it slightly slower. Obviously sending emails is never going to be quick which is why we need to send as many as possible at the same time.

Comment: @DavidRobinson : Have you tried splitting the mailing-list (inpList) by say 10, set the parallelism to 10 and on the split list do a ||-foreach, and in the task create a new client connection - creating a connection per mail is way too slow

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon: I've updated the code sample as there were some problems. As you can see in teh new code sample I have to create a new client and connection each time which is not ideal but exchange throws errors if I try to do anything different. From what I can gather I have to create a new connection each time otherwise exchange says things like 'sender already specified' or actually blocks other messages from being sent by throwing blocking errors.

Comment: From the documentation from SmtpClient: Only one send per Client may be active at any time, The only problem I see is _outboundQueueRepository.Remove since this manipulates the collection over which you are iterating. This is bad and will not work. Do something like marking the messages as sent and before sending check if it has already been sent.

Comment: For the error in exchange; I do not know a lot about exchange configuration, but as far as I know there is a limit of concurrent sends per user to block spammers. Talk to your exchange admin about that.

Comment: _outboundQueueRepository is fine and currently works without problems. I've discovered teh exchange error relates to your comment on 'Only one send per Client may be active at any time'. Basically it's trying to send a message which has not yet completed therefore exchange is stopping me sending another mail from the same address. This is solved with the new code snippet. I've also modified my exchange server to increase the concurrent sends but it was getting nowhere near the limit anyway. Thanks for your help, I think 6ish a second is the most I'm going to get.

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks to me like the way this works is that the Parallel.Foreach is creating some number of threads. Each thread is then creating an SMTP connection and then looping to send a batch of messages.

This seems pretty reasonable to me.

The only advice I can give you that might optimize this more is if many of these messages have the exact same content and the same From address and that the only difference is who the recipients are, you could vastly reduce the number of messages you need to send.

For example, if you are currently doing something like sending out the following 3 messages:

Message #1:

```
From: no-reply@company.com
To: Joe The Plumber <joe@plumbing-masters.com>
Subject: We've got a new sale! 50% off everything in stock!

some message text goes here.
```

Message #2

```
From: no-reply@company.com
To: Sara the Chef <sara@amazing-chefs.com>
Subject: We've got a new sale! 50% off everything in stock!

some message text goes here.
```

Message #3:

```
From: no-reply@company.com
To: Ben the Cobbler <ben@cobblers-r-us.com>
Subject: We've got a new sale! 50% off everything in stock!

some message text goes here.
```

Your code might create 3 threads, sending 1 of the messages in each of those threads.

But what if, instead, you created the following single message:

```
From: no-reply@company.com
To: undisclosed-recipients:;
Subject: We've got a new sale! 50% off everything in stock!

some message text goes here.
```

and then used the following code to send to all 3 customers at the same `MimeMessage`?

```
var sender = new MailboxAddress (null, "no-reply@company.com");
var recipients = new List<MailboxAddress> ();
recipients.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Joe the Plumber", "joe@plumbing-masters.com"));
recipients.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Sara the Chef", "sara@amazing-chefs.com"));
recipients.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Ben the Cobbler", "ben@cobblers-r-us.com"));

client.Send (message, sender, recipients);
```

All 3 of your customers will receive the same email and you didn't have to send 3 messages, you only needed to send 1 message.

You may already understand this concept so this might not help you at all - I merely mention it because I've noticed that this is not immediately obvious to everyone. Some people think they need to send 1 message per recipient and so end up in a situation where they try to optimize sending 1000's of messages when really they only ever needed to send 1.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is appreciated. Unforunately my scenario is slightly different and I'm effectively forwarding emails so cannot do this.

Comment: No problem. Glad you figured it out (I just read your solution) and thanks for sharing.

Comment: How does this help on the server side? The smtp client on the server still needs to connect to each mail server for each address individually...?

Comment: Yes, a server will need to connect to each mail server to send to each individual address.

Answer (score 1):

So we found a wider ranging fix which improved performance massively in addition to the improvements we found with the Parrallel ForEach loop. Not related to MailKit but I thought I would share anyway. The way that our calling code was creating our inputList was to use DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories to enumerate over all the first in the directory. In some cases our code took 2 seconds to execute over the directory with 40k files in it. We changed this to EnumerateDirectories and it effecitvely freed up the mail sending code to send many many emails.

So to confirm, the Parallel loop worked great, underlying performance issue elsewhere was the real bottleneck.