# Field "To" is empty when I Send email to many recipient by mailKit in C#

Tags: c#, mailkit

I've sent emails like  described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31459333/9752274
But Field "To" is empty. 
When I create a message (`new MimeMessage()`) of course I can't fill the field `To` because I sending email to many recipients.

See screenshot:

[image]

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: It sounds like to want to send emails to lots of people via `Bcc`.  It'd be helpful for you to confirm what your requirements are, and show the code that you currently have to send emails.

Comment: Please read [ask] and then ask a question. Also a [mcve] would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to send a message to X number of people and have each of them receive an email with their name & email address (and no one else's name & address) in the `To` header, then you will need to send 1 message per person.

There's no way around that.